# Python. NameError: global name is not defined (function without class)

Tags: python, function, runtime-error

everyone.

I have a problem with my Python script. Here is a problem code (there is "print" lines just for checking a value of variables):

```
def checkForHittingLevel(name, curValue, checkLine):
 match = bool(False)
 if checkLine is None:
  return match
 for parametersForCheck in checkLine.split(';'):
  if name in parametersForCheck:
   actionWithLevel = parametersForCheck.replace(name,'')
   # Just to check that it's not empty or there is any problem:
   print actionWithLevel[0]
   print type(actionWithLevel)
   if actionWithLevel[0] == '>':
    match = True if curValue > actionWithLevel[1:] else False
    break
   elif actionWithLevel[0] == '<':
    match = True if curValue < actionWithLevel[1:] else False
    break
   elif actionWithLevel[0] == '=':
    match = True if curValue == actionWithLevel[1:] else False
    break
   elif actionWithLevel[0] == '!':
    match = True if curValue != actionWithLevel[1:] else False
    break
   else:
    match = False
    break
 return match

incArgs.add_argument('-c', '--critical-list', type=str, dest='criticals',
 help='List of critical values for checking data')
inpValue = incArgs.parse_args()
[... some code here ...]
for checkLine in dNetCoreStatsOutData.splitlines():
 checkStatName = str(checkLine.split()[0])
  checkStatValue = int(checkLine.split()[1])
  for checkPrevDataLine in oldData.splitlines():
   if checkStatName in checkPrevDataLine:
    prevValue = int(checkPrevDataLine.split()[1])
    diffValue = checkStatValue - prevValue
    if checkForHititngLevel(checkStatName, diffValue, inpValue.criticals):
     ... code here ...
```

If I'm trying to run the script, I'm getting this output:

```
>
<type 'str'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line ###, in <module>
    if checkForHitingLevel(some_name, 20, 'some_name>10'):
  File "test.py", line ###, in checkForHittingLevel
    if actionWithlevel[0] == '>':
NameError: global name 'actionWithlevel' is not defined
```

If "print" command used then there is no problems with dealing with variable. But when I'm trying to get only specific char from the string I'm getting error.

I can't understand why does it happening. And if it's a normal behavior of the Python then how can I get chars from the line (for example via additional variable)? The only way that I know is to use "[]".

**PS** There is no difference if I'll try:

```
CheckResault = checkForHittingLevel(some_name, 20, 'some_name>10;name_2<10')
```

UPDATE: edited code, because there was a problem with some variable names.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4Opr.png)

UPDATE2: In my first example I used only part with function and how it should be called. I checked this example by itself and it works. But inside of full code it doesn't. So I added to the information above the part of the code that calls this function.

Comment: Where do you think `actionWithLevel` is defined? It's not defined in your current code. `actionAndlevel`, `actionWithlevel` and `actionWithLevel` are different variable names, if that's what has got you confused.

Comment: Just to clarify: `actionWithLevel` and `actionWithlevel` (note the `l`) are also different names.

Comment: Just a hint: `match = True if curValue > actionAndLevel[1:] else False`can be written as `match = curValue > actionAndLevel[1:]`. And please respect the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and use 4 spaces for indentation.

Comment: Hi, Mitch, Kirill.
Yes, you're right about names in the lines bellow. It is because the first name for variable was actionWithlevel. So I though that the cause of the problem could be in the name of variable and I changed it. But as you can see I did it not at the all lines.

Ok. I did it right this time (and updated the main question) and the problem is still here (and it would be here, because error happens before lines with wrong variable names)

Comment: Check your variable names *again*.

Comment: You still haven't fixed it. `actionAndLevel` is defined, `actionWithLevel` is not.

Comment: Hi, Matthias.
Thanks for advice about else part. it's just to be sure that in different case it should be false (if by some reason the default status of the variable will be corrupted. Well, just in case to be sure).
And I know about 4 spaces. It's just because it's too hard to read a code at the console editor if I have 5+ blocks (20+ spices).

Comment: Yes, sorry. Fixed names. Problem is still here.

Comment: Check your variable names ***again***. You ***still*** haven't gotten them right.

Comment: Also, the code in your screenshot is not the same as the code in your question or your error message.

Comment: Hi, user2357112. I did try to use ctrl+f to see that all variables are the same (+ notepad++ function with highlighting the same words). But I didn't saw any more misspells.
And thank you very much for information about different errors with screenshot. Because of this I did try to use only this code (and made Update2) and after this I did try to find why this example worked but my code didn't. And thanks to this I did found how to solve problem.

Answer (score 0):

You define at the beginning actionWithLevel.
Then you go on and compare actionWithlevel .. which you have never defined. Is it a different variable or just a typo? You use lower "l" instead of capital "L" . If you indeed want to make your comparisons with actionWithlevel (with lower "l"), you have to define it first.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did found the source of the problem. One of variables that were passed to function was defined after defining a function. This variable has been created by argparse (the name of variable is inpValue.criticals).
When I moved lines with `argparse` before `def checkForHititngLevel` the script stopped displaying error.
I don't know why it has this behavior, because `print` command in the function could work with this variable without any problems.